# Using Timestamp as ModifiedDate in the Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I was using the [`Timestamp` column of an Azure Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as `ModifiedDateTime` for `MyEntity`, and locally it seems pretty cool.

But once on the server, is not really clear if the `TimeStamp` is in local server time or in the UTC... because apprears the question how to display that column to the users...

**NB 1**
I did some tests, and the timestamp seem to follow the current UTC time, but I am not sure is because of the rule, or because the server actual location is in same timezone as the UK's UTC...

**NB 2**
There was already a similar question in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bca71fee-d3c4-4540-86e2-021561a84eaa/is-the-table-storage-timestamp-in-utc-time-or-server-local-time?forum=windowsazuredata)... but I didn't find something in the azure documentation explicitly on the `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `Timestamp` property is of type `DateTime`, which is UTC-based, and maintained by the storage service.

You can see this defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model).

Comment: Thanks. Is the same link I provided in the OP. What does mean DateTime is UTC "based"? Does it display only the UTC timezone?

Comment: It's UTC. Always. And not "displayed" as UTC - it's *stored* as UTC. You'd have to convert it to your local timezone if you wanted to display it as local time (or any other non-UTC time).